# trying to write a variable into a wp_query, need help!

Tags: loop, customization

I am not a php coder, I am a designer and html and css guy. However, I am stuck at the moment trying to write a piece of code that will find the name of a post, then get and display all of the posts that have that name as their category. Something like this,

Agent bio page has info about the agent and the bio post is his name and cat name.
He has listings under his name which is also his category in the wp backend under categories. So under the bio info, I need to create a function that will display a list of all of his posts and display them with the thumbnail, some excerpt text and a couple of the custom fields I have created.

this will be on a agent-single.php that will be used for every agent i have so it needs to find the post name with his slug in it and find posts based on that. Is there any way to actually do this or am I hoping for something that can not be done in wp?

```
  $template = basename(get_permalink());  // get agent here
  $taskarr = array (
    'post_type'   => 'listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category' => $template,
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num',
    'metakey'     => 'listing_date', // this is a custom field
    'metakey'     => 'location',
  );
  $tasks = get_posts($taskarr);
  foreach( $tasks as $task ) {
      //  Do stuff here, for example:
      echo '<li>';
      echo $task->post_title;
      echo $task->the_excerpt;
      echo $task->location;
          echo '</li>';
  }
```

this was inside my main loop which was a normal loop and of course it mutilates my code! ugh!!!

Comment: This can be done, but  you need to show us some actual code or what you have tried.

Comment: How is this different from your other question, "list posts of a person by a variable?"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [list posts of a person by a variable?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104617/list-posts-of-a-person-by-a-variable)

Comment: because I am not sure if I have been explaining this correctly, I have been working on it for 4 weeks to no avail. I have asked around the wp.org forums and no one can help me, I have tried everything under the sun to make it work and I am really no so sure what code I should put here as an example because none of them work and I am just simply frustrated and seeing red for the last 2 days, lol. Not to be a butt, but I have literally been up for the last 39 hours working on this and I cant even see my keys on my keyboard anymore, just blurry stuff all over the place, lol.

Comment: As of the last 13 hours I have simply been grasping at straws for any piece of code to get this to work, my last one I will post in the question above now.

Answer (score 0):

Using get_posts():

```
 <?php
      $category = get_category_by_slug($post->post_name);
      $template =  $category->term_id;
      $taskarr = array(
           'post_type' => 'listing',
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'category' => $template,
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
           'meta_key' => 'listing_date'
      );
      $tasks = get_posts($taskarr);
      foreach( $tasks as $task ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo $task->post_title;
           echo $task->post_excerpt;
           echo get_post_meta( $task->ID, 'location', 'single');
           echo '<li>';
      }
 ?>
```

Using WP_Query:

```
 <?php
       $catSlug = $post->post_name;
       $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'listing',
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'category_name' => $catSlug,
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
           'meta_key' => 'listing_date'

       );
       $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();
           echo '<li>';
           the_title();
           the_excerpt();
           echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'location', 'single');
           echo '<li>';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

Comment: looks very nice and simple, will this need to go int my main loop or will I have to wp_query in a multiple loop?

Comment: I updated it to match your query arguments.  I removed the extra meta key as you can only have one unless you do a meta_query

Comment: metakey --> meta_key ?

Comment: whoops... edited

Comment: Hey Thanks Eteich, I tried it and it simply made my page go blank, here is how I added your code, well I will post it as an answer I guess, here goes

Comment: well that didnt work so I will post my agent-single.php code here and you can see if I implemented it correctly.... well that didnt work either. i guess im going to bed, been up for nearly 2 days now and I am just about to throw this pc and the coffee out the friggen window, god I hate that wordpress is not built more like concrete5./

Comment: Alrigt, I modified some stuff and this is working in my sandbox on both the get post and WP_Query work.  It should be noted that $task->post_excerpt will only show if you have the excerpt box filled out.

Comment: for some reason the excerpt box is not showing up under my post editor anymore, lol.

Comment: You can add it to the page via the screen options tab at the top right of the screen.